# GridView select - passing values to textboxes on another form

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView with the select button turned on.

```
<asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
```

I want to pass the row values to TextBoxes that are on another page. So I am just working with on to test with the moment.

I am currently using the following code.

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Property_Name;
    Property_Name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
    Session["Property_Name"] = Property_Name;
    CreateSurvey CS = new CreateSurvey();
    CS.PropDetails();
    Response.Redirect("CreateSurvey.aspx");
```

This is my code from the second page (CreateSurvey.aspx)

```
public void PropDetails()
{
    var Property_Name = Session["Property_Name"];
    Create_PropName.Text = Property_Name.ToString();            
}
```

The "CreateSurvey.aspx" page opens but the `Create_PropName` TextBox is empty.

Am I missing something?

Comment: what's the result ? do you see QueryString ? Is it null ? Also rename Query string as PropName like `Response.Redirect("CreateSurvey.aspx?PropName=" + GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text);`

Comment: Having debugged the code, i can see when the value of PropName is going through to the second form ok, But when i hit the following piece of code.

var Property_Name = Session["Property_Name"];


            Create_PropName.Text = Property_Name.ToString();

i get the following error for the Create_PropName.text assignment

Create_PropName.Text = 'Create_PropName.Text' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'

Comment: can you update question with how you are reading query string values ?

Comment: Why are you using Session ? You haven't kept anything in session in earlier page right ?

Comment: I have updated my original question, as i did play with session see if it would make a difference

Answer (score 0):

try this
if you wan't to use session

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string Property_Name;
        Property_Name = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text;
        Session["Property_Name"] = Property_Name;
        //you don't need this as you already set session above
        //CreateSurvey CS = new CreateSurvey();
        //CS.PropDetails();
        Response.Redirect("CreateSurvey.aspx");
    }
```

while receiving you just need to call below code in page load

```
if(Session["Property_Name"] != null)
   Create_PropName.Text = Session["Property_Name"].ToString();
```

if you want to use query string

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Response.Redirect("CreateSurvey.aspx?PropName="+GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text);
    }
```

in second page load

```
if(Request.QueryString["Property_Name"] != null)
   Create_PropName.Text = Request.QueryString["Property_Name"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, i shall give them a go,
what would you advise is best to use, Session or Query String?

Comment: if it's just for navigating from one page to other you can just go with query string. Session is to keep the value all over the web application.

Comment: I have been using session and that works brilliantly, BUT, when I start sort the GridView, the select hyperlink becomes out of sync and reads the incorrect row.  How do I get round this,

see below post

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817664/c-sharp-gridview-refresh-index-after-applying-filter